# Firebase Function Promise Chain not catching errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using a Firebase function that detects when a Stripe Token is added to a user collection, which then creates a Stripe User and creates a Subscription for that user.

The problem I'm having is that the below code has an error in it, and whilst I need to figure out what that error is, the Promise Chain doesn't seem to catch the actual error.
All that logs out is `Function execution took 4375 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'`

Does anyone know why this is happening.  The only way I can get it to log catch the error is to nest the Promises.

```
exports.createStripeUser = functions.firestore
  // A Stripe Token is created in a user, therefore they have agreed to pay
  // Create a User in Stripe, and then attach the subscription to the Stripe customer
  .document('users/{userId}/stripe/{stripeCollectionId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const stripeToken = snap.data().stripeToken;
    let customer;
    return admin.auth().getUser(`${context.params.userId}`)
    .then(userObj => {
      const user = userObj.toJSON();
      return stripe.customers.create({
        email: user.email,
        source: stripeToken
      })
    })
    .then(cust => {
      customer = cust;
      return db.collection('users').doc(context.params.userId).collection('plan').doc(context.params.userId).get()
    })
    .then(plan => {
      return stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: customer.id,
        items: [{plan: plan.data().plan}]
      })
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log("ERRR", e)
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', e.message, e);
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your block in a

```
try {

} 
catch (e) { 
// e holds the nested error message 
}
```

block and pick up the error there.

Comment: OK, but is there any reason why the promise chain doesn't catch the error?

Comment: From my understanding it's because the chain's catch is only catching in one of the blocks, as opposed to being an overarching catch block for all the `.then`. I've always defaulted to a `try catch` to avoid problems like yours.

Comment: What's included in your `try { }` block?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, bug in the firebase code.  Although now the function says "ok" and everything has worked... that is strange.. I don't understand why that has worked at all..